# Chrome puts itself on Startup Applications

Tags: google-chrome, process, startup-applications

I don't know if this happened with Oneiric, but since I installed Precise I have noticed that Google Chrome put itself on my Startup Applications and processes like "chrome-no-startup-window", "chrome-sandbox", "chrome-sandbox", "chrome-type-zygote", etc. keep on running on the background.
If I remove Chrome from my Startup Applications, it will show back next time I start the computer.
How can I get Chrome to stop misbehaving like this?

Comment: Which version of Google chrome are you using?

Comment: i can tell you why this happening . If you click at firefox and Chrome , chrome will open first and after sometime firefox will open . if you look at the list before opening these you not gonna find anything with firefox . so make a quicker startup when user clicks on it chrome doing like this .

Comment: @tombrossman disable Chrome apps running on the background.That should technically solve the issue.

Answer (score 26):

I use Chromium not Chrome so they could be different, but try unchecking

```
Background Apps: (*) Continue running background apps when Chromium is closed
```

which is located at `chrome://settings/advanced` (or in `settings:under the hood` via the menus) down at the bottom of the page, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: +1 Tested and working, thanks. I have to [wait 24 hours](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/set-bounties) before I can award the bounty, so I'll do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

First of all kill each process:

```
sudo killall [process name]
```

Enable precise/universe repo and install bum:

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

Launch the program, find those services and remove them. Then reboot and see if they still load.

Comment: This does not solve the problem because Chrome does not behave like a system service, but simply adds itself to the user's autostart list.